# Remplazar texto en PHP

Tags: php, regex

Tengo una duda, tengo una frase que necesito eliminar cierto contenido, pero respetando el conjunto de la frase. Por ejemplo, la idea es eliminar los caracteres que vengan después de la palabra `por`.

```
$string = "Hace hoy un buen día para pasear por 3 forques, y lo que sea.";
```

Lo que necesito que devuelva la frase de la siguiente manera:

```
Hace hoy un buen día para pasear
```

Lo estoy haciendo de esta manera pero no se me ocurre como recuperar la frase..

```
preg_match("/por [0-9]{0,3}.+/", $string , $resultado);
// Devuelve-> "por 3 forques, y lo que sea."
```

¿Qué paso me falta?

Comment: estas indicando en tu expresión, que lea a partir de la palabra **por** cadenas y números en adelante

Comment: Es correcto @CarlosQuintero, la idea es después pasarle el String y lo compare para eliminar los caracteres con tengan después de la palabra **por** Dando como respuesta: **Hace hoy un buen día para pasear** que es lo que me falta todavía, a no se que se haga de otra manera ¿?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> eliminar los caracteres [...] después de la palabra **`por`** [...] pero respetando el conjunto de la frase.

Estás buscando eliminar, no coincidir con algo. Para eliminar, tenemos que reemplazar con [**preg_replace()**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php).

```
mixed preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] )
```

Y usamos el siguiente regex para que coincida con un espacio, `por` como palabra completa (`\b` coincide con límites de palabra), y luego cualquier cantidad de caracteres que no sean puntos ni saltos de línea (así consumimos hasta el final de la oración). De esta forma, respetamos el punto final de la oración.

```
/ por\b[^.\r\n]*/iu
```

O si se quiere eliminar desde  `por` hasta el final del texto:

```
/ por\b.*/isu
```

- El modificador `s` es para que `.*` también coincida con saltos de línea.
- El modificador `u` es para que `\b` incluya a caracteres Unicode al buscar el límite de palabra.
- El modificador `i` es para que ignore mayúsculas/minúsculas al buscar `por`.

---

Código:

```
$string = "Hace hoy un buen día para pasear por 3 forques, y lo que sea.";

$resultado = preg_replace ( '/ por\b[^.\r\n]*/iu' , '' , $string );

echo $resultado;
```

Resultado:

```
Hace hoy un buen día para pasear.
```

Comment: Una respuesta muy interesante @Mariano, tengo una duda, por qué simplemente no se usa un substring?

Comment: @JorgeLuis es otra alternativa, pero el autor de la pregunta está consultando específicamente usando expresiones regulares, preguntando qué paso le falta... Además de que se te complicaría con los límites de palabra en `oportuidad` por ejemplo

Comment: es una simple broma, pero hay preguntas que respeto los que mejores van a resolver

Comment: @Mariano lo único que puedo decir es que eres mi salvador, ya me has respondido a varias preguntas sobre PHP. Olé Tú!! Gracias Crack

Answer (score 1):

Muy fácil:

```
$text = "Hace hoy un buen día para pasear por 3 forques, y lo que sea.";
$part = strstr($text," por ");
$nuevoTexto = str_replace($part,"",$text);
echo $nuevoTexto;
```

También podrías tratar con:

```
$text = "Hace hoy un buen día para pasear por 3 forques, y lo que sea.";
$pos = strpos($text," por ");
$nuevoTexto = substr($text,0,$pos);
echo $nuevoTexto;
```

Espero te ayude.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu colaboración también @user3646126

Comment: Esto fallaría con un `por` separado por una coma. Ejemplo: `Buen día para pasear por, si tienen ganas, el bosque`.